# How do I resolve a Redirect URI error with Google Calendar API quickstart.php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm using

- Windows 10
- PHP 7.2
- Apache 2.4

I followed the directions at https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
When I open a Command Prompt an execute the command `PHP quickstart.php` I get the error:

```
First statement in the php.
Finished Outer IF isAccessTokenExpired.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI in C:\PHP\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php:637
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\PHP\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(328): Google\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
    #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\quickstart.php(60): Google_Client->createAuthUrl()
    #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\quickstart.php(81): getClient()
    #3 {main}
      thrown in C:\PHP\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php on line 637
```

I'm using the code from QuickStart

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
// [START calendar_quickstart]
//require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
print "First statement in the php.\n";

require 'C:\php\vendor\autoload.php';
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';

    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {

        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        print "Finished Outer IF isAccessTokenExpired.\n";
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            print "Finished Inner IF getRefreshToken.\n";
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
// [END calendar_quickstart]
```

It seems that it's failing on the statement  `if ($client->getRefreshToken())`
I can't understand why I would get an error on Quickstart code.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with the Quickstart.php. I looged the bug with Google, and they gave me an immediate fix. Delete the old `$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['localhost'] . '/oauth2callback.php');`  Then, right after the statement: `$client = new Google_Client();` add the new line: `$client->setRedirectUri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");` I also made new credentials by going to the console and then selected: **Create an OAuth Client ID**. I used an Application Type: **Other** then downloaded the Client Secret file and renamed it credentials.json. All is working well now.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you the redirect URL was not provided or correctly configured from the credentials page on Google's API console. OAuth needs to redirect back to your server where it will post the access token and refresh token used by their scripts.

If the OAuth flow can't properly redirect and send the credentials back to your server the script will not execute properly.

Comment: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

See step 3 under "Create authorization credentials" for more details.

Comment: I read the link.  So the QUICKSTART.PHP from Google missed this step?

Comment: You're right, that is strange. It should be baked in. Are you getting to the login to authorize the app? If so, where does it take you on submission?

Comment: It seems like it's failing on the statement "if ($client->getRefreshToken())".  From what the code comments say, if it can't find a token then it will ask the user to authenticate.  But it fails well in advance of that.

Comment: Can you post the contents of **credentials.json**? obscure or remove the contents of the client ID and client secret for security

Comment: {"web":{"client_id":"(client ID goes here).apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"calendar-api-(unique ID goes here)","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"(client_secret goes here"}}

Comment: To me it appears to be missing some pertinent pieces required to authorize an OAuth app. There is no client secret or redirect URI. When I click the "Enable the Google Calendar API" function from [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) I get a credentials file with far more details:

Comment: `{
 "installed": {
  "client_id": "1060706849474-nkudsjern8d242mdiv607tv4dentl07g.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "project_id": "api-project-1060706849474",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_secret": "9YLPGVaDCWuqChAR8yCc4Vrb",
  "redirect_uris": [
   "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
   "http://localhost"
  ]
 }
}`

Comment: I might suggest going back to the quickstart page and pulling a fresh *credentials.json* and see if that helps.

Comment: Hello Tshimkus.  There was a problem with the Quickstart.php.  I looged the bug with Google, and they gave me an immediate fix.  Delete the old $client->setRedirectUri..  Then, right after the statement: $client = new Google_Client(); add the new line: $client->setRedirectUri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");  I also

Comment: made new credentials by going to the console and then selected: Create an OAuth Client ID.  I used an Application Type: Other then downloaded the Client Secret file and renamed it credentials.json.  All is working well now.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Excellent. This should be posted as a new answer in case other people are having the same problem. Would you like to post the answer or should I?

Comment: I just added an answer.  Thanks again Tshimkus.